# Pandas masking a specific column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with 2 main columns--one called 'TIMESTAMP' representing dates, and one called 'QC' reflecting quality control flags as ints. This df has about 40,000 rows so I do not want to iterate over each one.

I have a new dataframe (dfNew) with just two columns of several start and end date pairs. I want to go through my original df and for all rows where the TIMESTAMP falls in between any of the start-end date pairs listed in dfNew, I want to replace the QC value with -1. This dfNew has about 400 rows so I figured iterating here would not be too bad.

The df looks something like this:

```
TIMESTAMP       | QC
2019-05-04 00:22    5
2019-05-04 00:24    1
2019-05-09 03:30    3
```

the dfNew looks something like this:

```
START         | END
20190504_0023   20190504_0024
```

So I would want to replace QC=1 for the second row in df with QC=-1.

This is my code so far:

```
for index, row in dfNew.iterrows():
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    masked = (df['TIMESTAMP'] >= start) & (df['TIMESTAMP'] <= end)
    df['QC'].mask(masked, -1)
```

However for some reason, the mask is not working. No values get replaced with -1. I think it may have something to with the fact that I'm creating the mask using the TIMESTAMP column but trying to use that mask to replace values in the QC columns, but I cannot figure out what it is. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that you need to set the column values equal to the applied mask: `df['QC'] = df['QC'].mask(masked, -1)`.

You only need to convert the 'TIMESTAMP' column to datetimes once outside of the loop. Assuming you have multiple rows in dfNew, the start and end times change for each row, so this stays inside the loop.

```
# this should be outside of the loop
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])

for index, row in dfNew.iterrows():
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    masked = (df['TIMESTAMP'] >= start) & (df['TIMESTAMP'] <= end)
    df['QC'] = df['QC'].mask(masked, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP)
dfNew.START = pd.to_datetime(dfNew.START, format='"%Y%m%d_%H%M"')
dfNew.END = pd.to_datetime(dfNew.END, format='"%Y%m%d_%H%M"')

def f(row):
    df.loc[df['TIMESTAMP'].between(row[0], row[1]), 'QC'] = -1

dfNew.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean select

```
m=df.QC==1
```

Use .loc accessor

```
df.loc[m,'QC']=-1
```

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified that the initial QC value can be arbitrary so I only wanted to use timestamp as the criteria in the mask. I think one of the answers below is working. Thank you anyways though! :)